# Newsletter is difficult to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I have a bit of a difficult time reading the newsletter, the black text on a dark blue background is tough. I expect a white background like the main page, but it doesn't load.

I am using gmail and Firefox 8.0.

I receive a number of other SE newsletters and none of the others have this issue.

[image: Home Improvement Newsletter screenshot]

Comment: Not an answer but when I use chrome and view it in the browser it looks just like yours.  but I use Thunderbird from Mozilla (Firefox) [this is what I get.](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwVroAj7GS9tOGRmZjQxMzMtYzc1My00OTdiLWE1ZDUtZDc1NTY2MzFkZGY3) I can't answer the question but I did want to throw this out there also.

Comment: thx @ChrisF, I tried to add those tags, but was unable to due to rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now.

I was able to reproduce this in Gmail/Chrome. Apparently, in Gmail, if any one of the inline styles includes an `rgba` value, the *entire* style attribute is stripped. I'm not sure how recently this began occurring. Email HTML is always a mystery :/

Comment: will accept when next home improvement newsletter is sent out and issue resolved